# Deriving Values from Attribute Table for Value Table in Python Toolbox of ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, value-table

I would like to derive the values in the value table dynamically based on the given input shapefile. I managed to derive the values but I'm not able to delete or move any of those values if I use the provided buttons in the toolbox.

Assuming, an attribute table (which is provided as parameter 0) has 10 features and in field "purpose" are the values "purpose1","purpose2" and "purpose3" (each of those values occurs several times but I only want the unique values). The value table should (after providing the shapefile) be automatically filled with those three values from above. If another SHP is provided (lets assume with the values "purpose_a", "purpose_b", "purpose_c", than the former values shall be replaced by the latter.

[image: Overview of Value Table with the delete, move up and down buttons on the right]

The values in the value table shall be derived based on a field in the provided input shapefile.

What I did so far:

```py
class ExportWells(object):    
def __init__(self):
    """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
    self.label = "some_tool"
    self.description = "some_tool"
    self.canRunInBackground = False

def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    global sl_purpose
    #list with all possible values of purpose
    sl_purpose = [[u"purpose1"],[u"purpose2"],[u"purpose3"],[u"purpose_a"],[u"purpose_b"],[u"purpose_c"]]

    input_shp = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input Shapefile",
        name="in_shp",
        datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
    input_shp.filter.list = ["POINT"]

    purpose = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "purpose",
        name = "sl_purpose",
        datatype = "GPValueTable",
        parameterType = "Optional",
        direction = "Input")
        purpose.columns = [["GPString", "purpose"]]
        purpose.values = sl_purpose
    params = [input_shp,purpose]
    return params

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    global sl_purpose
    if parameters[0].altered:
        get_selection_values = [[shp_values[0]] for shp_value in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(parameters[0].valueAsText,["purpose_field"])]
        sl_purpose_list = list(set([purpose_value[0] for purpose_value in get_selection_values]))
        sl_purpose_modified = [[sl_purpose_item]for sl_purpose_item in sl_purpose_list if sl_purpose_item]
        parameters[1].values = [profile_status_val for profile_status_val in parameters[1].values if profile_status_val in sl_profile_status_modified]
        #1. attempt - assign derived list (without any global variables)
        #parameters[1].values = sl_profile_status_modified
        #2. attempt - assign those values from global sl_purpose which are in the derived list
        #parameters[1].values = [profile_status_val for profile_status_val in sl_purpose if profile_status_val in sl_profile_status_modified]
    return
```

Unfortunately, the result is not satisfying at all. My first attempt, to simply assign the list of values to the value table works in so far that the values are written in the value table. Unfortunately, the functionality of the buttons (move up and down, delete etc.) is gone. The same behaviour occurs with my second approach. This has another disadvantage, that I have to provide a list with all possible values in the getParametersInfo (or alternatively in the **init** which doesn't work neither).

The third approach works a bit better (at least, the functionality of the buttons is given) but it has the same drawback, that I have to provide a list with all possible values (I tried to provide an empty list, but that didn't work). The problem here is, that it doesn't update the value list properly in the case of changing input shapefiles.

Does anybody have an idea how to cope with that?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4.1

Comment: I don't understand what you want to see in your end-result.  As I read it you are wanting to pull values from a user specified shapefile into a value table in your toolbox dialog, is that correct?  I don't understand what you are wanting to do with up/down/delete buttons here.  Could you [edit] your question to perhaps include a screenshot diagram of what you expect to get, and some info on what you'd like to do with it?  Please also include details of each of your three approaches so we know what you've tried.

Comment: yes, I want to pull values from the specified shapefile. The buttons on the right are always provided when using a GPValueTable datatype. I want a user to be able to either delete or change the order of these values by using those buttons. Unfortunately, this does not work properly in my case.